# TSX language support for PhpStorm

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, reactjs, tsx

I'm using PhpStorm for a web project, and I'd like to use [TSX language](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-16%29) (Typescript/JSX) however it doesn't seem to be supported.

I'd like to continue to use PhpStorm and avoid switching between other IDE's.

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to [PhpStorm EAP version](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) (a development version of a new PhpStorm release).

It is typically stable enough and it should support TSX to some extent. There will be [bugs](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=TSX) though.

Comment: Thanks for the response and links. Do you know when the stable version will be released?

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Previous+PhpStorm+Releases this may give you a clue. :)

Comment: Every 6 months or so it would seem. So probably in december. Thanks for the information. I'll try out the EAP and see how it goes.

Comment: But to assure you a little, I use the development version all the time and it works for me just fine.